# is there a way to move winsock lib from windows to ubuntu?

Tags: ubuntu, codeblocks, winsock2

I've created a `server` project in Windows 7 using `winsock` library. However, My friend want to use this project in `Ubuntu` with `Code::Blocks` framework. When I move the project to `Ubuntu`, I realize that there's no `winsock` library!! So, I want to ask for a suggestion to use `winsock` lib in Ubuntu or a way to run my project in `ubuntu`. Thanks!

Answer (score 1):

Instead of linking with ws2_32 library (winsock on windows) you instead need to link against glibc which you always do when building with g++ / gcc.

You will however need to replace some system calls with #ifdef's.
For example on linux you have close() instead of closesocket(), ioctl() instead of ioctlsocket() and so on.

Try using this block in your code:

```
#if defined(__unix__)
typedef int SOCKET;
#define closesocket(i) close(i)
#define ioctlsocket(i,l,ul) ioctl(i,l,ul)
#endif
```

And for your sockets you will need to use the typedef SOCKET.

Comment: Yeap! I'm trying! Thanks you!